# Interactive plot with Slider using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

How do I recreate the following interactive plot in Python using Plotly?

My simple example draws a bar chart with one column x and another 1-x.

GIF from Mathematica:

[image]

Slider allows for a varying x between 0 and 1.

Mathematica code:

```
Manipulate[BarChart[{x, 1 - x}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
    {{x, 0.3, "Level"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

---

UPDATE

Here is a solution which I don't like:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import ipywidgets as widgets
```

Plotting:

```
def update_plot(x):
    data = [go.Bar(
                x=['1', '2'],
                y=[x, 1-x]
    )]
    iplot(data, show_link=False)

x = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=1, value=0.3)
widgets.interactive(update_plot, x=x)
```

Problems with this:

- The plot twinkles when the slider is moved
- The slider is misplaced
- The increment is not granular enough
- I cannot specify a precise value myself

Comment: Please have a look at https://plot.ly/python/sliders/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? If you have a specific question about a piece of code, the Stackoverflow community will be happy to help.

Comment: I think the question is pretty specific.The documentation you've sent me to is very poor. If you choose to explain something by example, at least show a few more.

Comment: Yes, the question is rather specific on a general standpoint. However, on the context of SO, it is actually quite broad. Have you read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) wiki? Take a look there and you'll see asking for a solution to this kind of problem is not very welcomed by the community. I'd recommend making a more extensive search on the subject at hand, since it seems like a quite trivial situation, and surely someone tackled it in the past.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from Plotly 3.0 this can be achieved as follows (in JupyterLab):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import interact
```

```py
fig = go.FigureWidget()
bar = fig.add_bar(x=['x', '1-x'])
fig.layout = dict(yaxis=dict(range=[0,1]), height=600)

@interact(x=(0, 1, 0.01))
def update(x=0.3):
    with fig.batch_update():
        bar.y=[x, 1-x]
fig
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

From Plotly 4.0 you need to specify `fig.data[0].y` instead of `bar.y`.

Comment: Instead of getting a plot, I get a description, i.e. FigureWidget({
    'data': [{'type': 'bar', 'uid': 'a5139b4a-4b23-4938-a93b-86e0397b2495', 'x': ['x', '1-x'], …

Answer (score 6):

Code below creates an interactive plot in `plotly` and `Dash`. It takes two inputs: slider and text box.  When the code below saved as a '`.py`' and the file is run in terminal, it should run a local server in the terminal. Next, copy the `* Running on http://` address from this server and paste it in browser to open the plot. Most likely it would be `http://127.0.0.1:8050/`. Resources: [1](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/), [2](https://plot.ly/python/sliders/), [3](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components) . (`Python 3.6.6`)

*Important: Please note that for the slider to work, the text box value has to be reset to '`0`' (zero).*

**Import libraries**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly import __version__
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
```

**Create Dash app**

```
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(
      html.Div([
            html.Div([html.H5("Level"),

                    dcc.Slider(id='slider_input',
                                min=0,
                                max=1,
                                step=0.005,
                                value=0.1,
                    )],style={'width': '200'}
                ),

            html.Div(style={'height': '10'}),

            html.Div(dcc.Input( id='text_input',
                        placeholder='Enter a value...',
                        type='text',
                        value=0.0
                    ),style={'width': '50'}),

            dcc.Graph(id='example',
                     figure={'data':[{'x':[1,2],
                                      'y':[0,1],
                                      'type':'bar',
                                      'marker':dict(color='#ffbf00')
                                     }],
                              'layout': go.Layout(title='Plot',
                                                  #xaxis = list(range = c(2, 5)),
                                                  yaxis=dict(range=[0, 1])
                                                   )
                               })

          ], style={'width':'500', 'height':'200','display':'inline-block'})
)

# callback - 1 (from slider)
@app.callback(Output('example', 'figure'),
             [Input('slider_input', 'value'),
             Input('text_input', 'value')])

def update_plot(slider_input, text_input):
    if (float(text_input)==0.0):
        q = float(slider_input)
    else:
        q = float(text_input)

    figure = {'data': [go.Bar(x=[1,2],
                              y=[q, 1-q],
                              marker=dict(color='#ffbf00'),
                              width=0.5
                       )],
              'layout': go.Layout(title='plot',
                                  #xaxis = list(range = c(2, 5)),
                                  yaxis=dict(range=[0, 1])
                                )
            }
    return figure
```

**Run server**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Edit - 1  .............................**

*Plot with slider only*

The code below uses plotly without dash. The plot is interactive with a slider. Note that this code does not have a text input to change the plot (as above). However, the plot below should update with slider without the need to 'release' the slider to see the update. In this plot, individual traces were created for plotting.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly import __version__
%matplotlib inline

import json
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot 
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()
```

**Create traces**

```
traces = []
q = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
for i in range(0,len(q)):
    trace = dict(
                type = 'bar',
                visible = False,
                x=[1, 2],
                y=[q[i], 1 - q[i]],
                marker=dict(color='#ffbf00'),
                width=0.5
             )
    traces.append(trace)

traces[0]['visible'] = 'True'
```

**Create slider**

```
steps=[]
for i in range(len(traces)):
    step = dict(
        method = 'restyle',  
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(traces)],
        label=""
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active = 10,
    currentvalue = {"prefix": "Level: "},
    #pad = {"t": 50},
    steps = steps

)]
```

**Create layout**

```
layout = go.Layout(
    width=500,
    height=500,
    autosize=False,
    yaxis=dict(range=[0, 1])
)

layout['sliders'] = sliders
```

**Plot figure**

```
fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)

#pyo.iplot(fig, show_link=False) # run this line to view inline in Jupyter Notebook
pyo.plot(fig, show_link=False) # run this line to view in browser
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Do you know how to make it have synchronous updating (i.e. change the chart while I move the slider)?

Comment: I looked up the docs for `dash`, and it seems the `slider` has to be released to see an effect. (https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/slider). I have added another code in Edit-1 using plotly only. This slider in this plot is more responsive. Please note that this plot does not have a text input to update the plots.