# How to animate plotly bar chart in python

Tags: python, plotly

I have a working piece of code for a bar plot in plotly using python 3.7.  The code is copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367567/interactive-plot-with-slider-using-plotly) question.  However, when I try to animate the transition the interaction stops completely.  Below when step['method'] = 'restyle' the code performs as expected.  However, when the step['method'] is set to 'animate' the interactions do not work.
Is there a mistake in my code, or is this a limitation of plotly in python?  I have seen similar examples in js that work correctly.

```
for i in range(len(traces)):
    step = {
        'method': 'animate',  # 'restyle' works as expected
        'args': ['visible', [False] * len(traces),
                 {
                     'transition': {'duration': 300}
                 }],
        'label': ""
    }
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)
```

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't know if this might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/48) .

Comment: As you can tell from my reputation, I am relatively new to stackoverflow.  I didn't want to clutter the question with the MCVE which is why I listed the other question.  Also, thank you for updating my question and giving it a dynamic link.  What I find odd is that the code seems to work for the JS version but not python.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) and follow this [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) will help you to receive a answer in little time and other people with the same problem to found the solution. So do not think a mcve will clutter the question. On the other side you can't pretend that users go to check your other questions to answer this one ;)