# How can I get a slider similar to ipywidgets in Plotly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, slider, plotly-dash

I have a simple function which plots a horizontal line to a certain value of x that is defined in a function as shown below:

```
def plot_lines(x):

    plt.hlines(y = 10,
              xmin = 0,
              xmax = x)
    
    plt.xlim(0, 10)

    plt.show()
```

Using ipywidgets, I can get a slider where x is the value I interact with. It looks as follows

```
from ipywidgets import *

x = widgets.IntSlider(value = 2,
                     min = 0, 
                     max = 10,
                     )

interact(plot_lines, x = x)
```

My output looks as follows:
I can drag along the slider to change the value of x. As a result, the plot changes accordingly.

I defined a function `plot_lines` here and the argument that I pass `x` acts as an interactive parameter.

[image]

I am relatively new to Plotly. Is it possible to get a slider in a similar manner in Plotly? How would the equivalent implementation of this simple function look like in Plotly?

Comment: Plotly: [Slider](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider) + [Basic Callback](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks)

Comment: Plotly: [Simple Slider Control](https://plotly.com/python/sliders/)

Comment: [python - Interactive plot with Slider using Plotly - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367567/interactive-plot-with-slider-using-plotly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution to this on my own:

```
def hlines(x):
    
    fig1 = go.FigureWidget()
    
    fig1.add_hline(y = 10,
                   x0 = 0,
                   #Normalize value for x between min and max
                   x1 = x,
                   line_color = "blue"
             )
    
    #Update ranges for x and y axis
    fig1.update_xaxes(range=[0, 10])
    fig1.update_yaxes(range=[0, 15])

    fig1.show()

#x takes normalized value.
interact(hlines, x = 0.5)
```

One thing to be noted is that in Plotly, it seems the x is taking normalized value between min and max in the xaxes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are options

#### native plotly

- use **rangeslider**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(x=np.linspace(1,10,20), y=np.sin(np.linspace(1,10,20)))
fig.update_layout(xaxis={"rangeslider":{"autorange":True}, "range":[1,5]})
```

[image]

#### ipywidgets

- update xaxis **range**

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

def widget_slider(x):
    return fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[1,x])

fig = px.line(x=np.linspace(1,10,20), y=np.sin(np.linspace(1,10,20)))

interact(widget_slider, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=10, step=1, value=5))
```

[image]